# Flash using AS3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I created a movie clip called splash_mc that I only want to be viewed on the "splash page". However, when I link my splash_mc to the main timeline, or any other movie clip, it (of course) spreads it across all my frames as I'm clicking though the various links on my navbar. Basically, I just want the animation to appear under the designated label "splash" so that when I click the links going to my other pages in my main navigation the animation disappears. I tried using 'this.removeChild' by placing my animation in with my navigation movieClip and it worked. But only when i first use the nav on my splash page; when I try clicking the links from my internal pages I get an error, since the eventListener was still running the function but of course there's no longer a the splash_mc to get rid of.

What can I do? I saw here where I could just load my splash_mc to one frame, so when my links are clicked, theoretically, the playhead moves off that frame and my animation is no longer viewable. Is this a better option?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Either way is acceptable. I guess it really depends on which methods you prefer. You can eliminate that error by using removeEventListener() in the same function that does the removeChild.